# Conditional PHP in at Wordpress Header

Tags: php, wordpress

I added,

`<div style="margin:0"><a href="#">Sign in</a> | <a href="#">Register</a> | <a href="#">My Account</a> </div>`

at the header of the wordpress website. Now i want to make a function for that. If user stay as logged it then only "My account" will show there with hyperlink and if user not logged in then it will show "Sign in " and "Register" with hyperlink.

May be wordpress logged in check PHP code is,

`<?php if ( !is_user_logged_in() )  ?>`

But i am not sure.

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/connect-button-to-disappear-on-success-how

follow this topic. It will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(!is_user_logged_in()){
?>
<div style="margin:0"><a href="#">Sign in</a> | <a href="#">Register</a>
<?php }else{ ?>
<a href="#">My Account</a> </div>
<?php } ?>
```